# Can't access nginx from outside server

Tags: nginx, http

Here I am again with yet again another strange error with nginx.

I am running a server with debian and nginx as webserver. Everything was working fine until it suddenly stopped accepting connections from outside the server. I can't access the website from any browser (throughs `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`), I can't connect using telnet to the server IP, server IP and port 80 or 443... but I can access through the port 22, so SSH and FTP are working.

If through SSH I do `curl IP` it shows the content of my HTML.

As I said, everything was working before, it was all of a sudden, without doing any change on the server.

Also nginx it's running and not showing any error.

I am totally lost to be honest. Any ideas about why this happens and how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

Here is the **access.log**. It doesn't show any of the times I try to access the website from any browser.

```
94.23.253.89 - - [19/Nov/2015:00:47:57 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
94.23.253.89 - - [19/Nov/2015:00:48:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
94.23.253.89 - - [19/Nov/2015:00:48:23 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5194 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
```

And here is the result of **netsat -ltnp**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/nginx -g daemon
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      940/nginx -g daemon
```

**EDIT 2** I forgot to mention that I am also running iRedMail (dovecot, postfix, fail2ban)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the nginx access logs? If not give that a go and report back with your findings. Also, go ahead and run `netstat -ntlp` and see if nginx is listening on the port you've defined in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: select services not available, but locally those services are available. Firewall springs to mind

Comment: I just updated the post with the result.

Comment: I thought about it, here's the IP tables regarding HTTP: ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http

Comment: Is it hosted anywhere that might have an external firewall such as ec2/azure

Comment: @Drifter104 My server is from OVH. They say they have anti DDoS protection, but not network firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, problem solved. Apparently I was trying to access too many times to my email and I was banned by fail2ban... Sorry for the trouble guys :(

Comment: Maybe just do one new thing at a time?

Comment: @Paul I definitely should :/

Comment: @peterh I thought you had to wait a couple of days before having the option to accept your own answer.

Comment: @Paul Right - okay. :-)